# Running a 32-bit JVM is not supported in this platform in Intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea, compilation, 32-bit

While compiling my project, I'm getting error as '**Running a 32-bit JVM is not supported in this platform**'.

**When I get this error:**

And I get this error when I change my JDK home path to '64-bit JDK' under Project structure -> Platform settings -> SDKs.

**Current Solution :**

Now if I change my SDK back to 32-bit JDK, it works fine. But when I have my SDK as 64-bit JDK, I'm getting the error as **Running a 32-bit JVM is not supported in this platform**.

**My Question**
Instead of changing my JDK, how to get out of this problem.

More than that, my question is in, "**Running a 32-bit** JVM is not supported". Actually I'm not running any JVM here in Intellj. I'm just compiling my Java Source to get a .class files. What is the word **running** mean here...

Comment: Missing an important piece of information - is your operating system 32- or 64-bit?

Comment: @gknicker Mine is MAS OSX 64 Bit

Comment: Thank you. If I understand correctly, you have two distinct JDKs installed - a 64-bit JDK and a 32-bit JDK. Is that right?

Comment: @gknicker ya I have 2 distict JDK installed

Comment: Please type this on a command line and tell me the results: `java -d64 -version`. Also, please read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15827430/running-a-64-bit-jvm-is-not-supported-on-this-platform-with-java-d64-option-o and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9512603/installing-32-bit-jvm-on-64-bit-linux so we can determine whether those posts help your issue.

Comment: @gknicker oh I'm getting Running a 64-bit JVM is not supported on this platform. on 32 Bit SDK and Running a 32-bit JVM is not supported on this platform. in 64-bit SDK if I type java -d32 -version respectively...

Comment: @gknicker Thanks for your time. I already read those posts before posting this question. Anyway for now, I'll use 32-bit JDK itself. Let see whether can I get any insights on this. Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

We have determined that your operating system is MAC OSX 64-bit, and that you have two JDKs installed, both the 32-bit and the 64-bit version.

[Other threads on this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15827430/running-a-64-bit-jvm-is-not-supported-on-this-platform-with-java-d64-option-o) indicate problematic behavior when [these two JDKs are installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9512603/installing-32-bit-jvm-on-64-bit-linux) on the same machine. When you run java command line with `-d32` you get the error "Running 64-bit JVM is not supported on this platform" and when you run java command line with `-d64` you get the error "Running 32-bit JVM is not supported on this platform".

Therefore, I highly recommend you uninstall the 32-bit JDK, then re-install the 64-bit JDK.

Comment: ----I highly recommend you uninstall the 32-bit JDK, then re-install the 64-bit JDK.---- No I need 32 Bit JDK for DCEVM purpose on MAC OS.